# Symfony / api-platform Adding provider to PATCH routes couses empty values error

Tags: rest, symfony, api-platform.com

In my `user` entity I declared 2 PATCH routes. Both of these require token authentication to access. I wanted to provide user data from the token instead of the uri variable. After creating custom data provider, my routes however broke completely. Using the route with custom state processor I was able to diagnose that data provider always returns almost fully null object. I had no problems with data providers before but I didn't use them for PATCH. Am i missing some annotation? Api platform documentation is really lacking and examples are hard to find. I'm theorizing that it still tries to access users from original url that is users/{id}

```php
user entity:
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(
            normalizationContext: ['groups'=> ['user:read']],
        ),
        new Patch(//for password and email
            name: 'credentials',
            uriTemplate: '/users/credentials',
            processor: UserCredentialsPersistStateProcessor::class,
            validationContext: ['groups' => ['user:write_credentials']],
            denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['user:write_credentials']],
            security: "is_granted('ROLE_REDDIT_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
            securityMessage: "Only user himself can modify his settings.",
            provider: UserFromTokenProvider::class,
            // input: User::class,
        ),
        new Patch(// for all other settings 
            uriTemplate: '/users',
            denormalizationContext: ['groups'=> ['user:write']],
            security: "is_granted('ROLE_REDDIT_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
            securityMessage: "Only user himself can modify his settings.",
            provider: UserFromTokenProvider::class,
        ),
         //rest of routes
    ],
)]
```

```php
class UserFromTokenProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private UserRepository $repository,
        private Security $security
    ) {
    }

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): User|null
    {
        $currentUser = $this->security->getUser();
        if ($currentUser !== null) {
            $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(['login' => $currentUser->getUserIdentifier()]);
            return $user;

        } else {
            throw new ItemNotFoundException('Token is not assosiated with user.', 404);
        }
    }
}
```

```json
result from var dump:
object(App\Entity\User)#6754 (17) {
  ["id":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["login":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["nickname":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["email":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["newEmail":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  string(16) "user@example.com"
  ["description":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["password":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["plainOldPassword":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  string(6) "string"
  ["plainPassword":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  string(6) "string"
  ["isNSFW":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["roles":"App\Entity\User":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "ROLE_USER"
  }
```

I tried to modify the provider, returning null, full object with id of 1, trowing exceptions with always the same result.

Comment: Doesn't this `$this->security->getUser()` already give you a proper user model? Why loading the same model again from DB? If you want to `PATCH` user data, where is the instruction to do so?

Comment: Further, for `PATCH` you need a `Processor` not a `Provider`. See State Processors here https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-processors/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, from a security, I'm only provided with login and token, after which I have to query the database to retrieve the complete package of information corresponding to the login. It's unique in my project, so there shouldn't be any issues.  I've already added a custom state processor to one of the PATCH routes, but when I var_dump, data variable is empty. I thought that using providers would enable me to modify the data before passing it to processor. I hoped it  would help in splitting the code to avoid giant processors that do multiple things.

Comment: But you are right, I probably should try to use a custom denormalizer for this instead of a provider. I'll wait for a reply on my GitHub issue first though. Maybe there is an easier way. [issue](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/2647)